# Currentregion is giving wrong bounds

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select cells but excel is bugged.

```
Public Property Get RangeData() As Range
    If Me.GenerateTable = True And ObjectDBRExists(Me.Name) = True Then
        Set RangeData = ASheet.ListObjects(Me.Name).DataBodyRange
    ElseIf Me.GenerateTable = False Or ObjectDBRExists(Me.Name) = False Then
        Dim r As Integer
        If Me.RangeFields.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count < 2 Then r = 2 Else r = Me.RangeFields.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        Set RangeData = Me.RangeFields.Rows(2 & ":" & r)
    End If
    MsgBox Me.RangeFields.Address & " " & Me.RangeFields.CurrentRegion.Address
End Property
```

Is it possible for above that `Me.RangeFields.CurrentRegion` is having $B$6 to $F$10 range while RangeFields has $B$8? Ctrl+A in excel is selecting only the headers and bounds of the table.

[image]

Also if you are asking why I don't select databodyrange it's because it can be empty or there could be no table...

Comment: What are you expecting `CurrentRegion` to return? I guess I'm a bit confused by your question. Also just for context, what exactly are you trying to do? Maybe there's an answer that doesn't rely on `CurrentRegion`.

Comment: I am expecting range B8 to F10. But instead it returns range B6 to F10. But it be that excel is prioritizing table while VBA will go to B6 because of "a%" inside of the above cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it appears that VBA is using above cell and extends currentregion over B8.
I could use `Range(Range("B8:F8"), Range("B8:F8").End(xlDown)).Select` but I don't think this will go over empty cells.